# How to clear a "Format as Table" from an Excel worksheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to format a worksheet using the **Format as Table** tool:
[image]

However I am receiving an error: *"A table can't overlap another table"*.

My worksheet was previously formatted using **Format as Table**, so it makes sense that I would need to remove it before re-formatting it.  I attempted to clear it via the `Home -> Editing -> Clear -> Clear Formats` option.

[[image]

And that certainly seemed to work visually, but when attempting to re-apply Format as Table, I receive this error: 
[[image]

I'm assuming that the Table format is still there but without any visible formatting. How do I delete the actual table format so that I can apply a new table format?

I am using Microsoft Excel for Office 365: 16.0.12026.20194 64-bit.

Comment: Try to converted it to range and inserted a new table.

Answer (score 1):

I think the format as a `table/clear format` is just formatting, it doesn't `create/remove` the actual underlying table. Use the `convert to range` under `table design`

[image]